# How to draw diagrams in Open Office?

Tags: openoffice, diagrams

I would like to draw diagrams using Open Office but I didn't find any installed by default. What I am exactly looking for are diagrams that look like the ones that come with MS Office 2007/2010 (like Pyramid diagrams, Star diagrams etc.).

Any idea? A plugin to install? Otherwise are there any online services that can do it? (I have tested Cacoo and gliffy but they don't really offer the diagrams that I am looking for).

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenOffice has a program called Draw built in which is for drawing whatever you want.

*File* -> *New* -> *Drawing*

It does charts, graphs, vector drawings, whatever you want.

Answer (score 5):

OO Draw is fairly elaborate -- somewhere between MS Visio and Adobe Illustrator or GNU Gimp.  The sort of diagrams the Original Poster describes are more like MS PowerPoint, which corresponds to OO Impress, rather than Draw.

There are a large number of OpenOfficetemplates [available online here](http://templates.services.openoffice.org/).  You can also look for StarOffice and LibreOffice templates; all the templates will work in all those related applications.  You may also want to check [opentemplate.org](http://opentemplate.org), but they seem to be more oriented toward decorative backdrops than diagram templates.